# How to send auto replies to customer to case acknowledgment mail

Tags: email2case

We are sending case acknowledgement mail to customer, whenever customer creates a case through website. If customer replies to acknowledgement mail, reply will be saving into case by use case thread id. Now we want to stop replies from customer, if we receive a reply from customer we want to send automatic reply saying that email is no longer exists, and if we receive case through particular mail case status should be 'Closed'.

Answer (score -2):

You can use Case Auto-Response Rules

Comment: I would like to see there be more substance to this answer.